# Is it possible to Execute Maven Project from Jenkins or TFS? Is it even possible without access to the M2 Repo Directory?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Is it possible to Execute Maven Project(s) from Jenkins or TFS using GitHub? Is it even possible without access to the M2 Repo Directory?

1) For example I push my project to GitHub.
2) Then I trigger the build in `TFS or jenkins` using the GitHib link.
3) Is it even possible if i have no access to the m2 repo directory on GitHub?

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: why do you need access to m2 repo on GitHub?

Comment: @Paras for example if i push my whole project on github and then invoke the project using jenkins and the GitHub link, on a virtual machine which contains jenkins but no reference of the project, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to run your project through jenkins providing the `github` url but for that you have to configure Jenkins and provide access to your github project.

You may refer [this](https://community.perfectomobile.com/posts/1010021-maven-github-jenkins-testng-integration-ci-automation)

Comment: thanjks so much for your help, would i need to upload the .M2 repo and all .JAR files required? thanks again

Comment: no you don't need to upload .m2 repo... whenever `jenkins` would checkout your project and do a first run. It will create a `.m2 repository` on the machine where jenkins is hosted and download all the jars which are mentioned in your `pom.xml`. Provided Maven is installed in the machine. Thats the advantage of maven. You dont' have to take care of library files right.